# using SQL SERVER can create xml Document like

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

IN SQL SERVER can create XML Document like following format with every column name come with Datafield FieldName="Batch"

CID,BATCH,EXP_DATE are column names.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGlcR.png)

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: `SELECT … FOR XML` - [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178107.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @stuartd It's not that simple... `FOR XML` does not support fieldnames like above *out-of-the-box*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT 'BATCH' AS [DataField/@fieldName]
      ,BATCH AS [DataField]
      ,''
      ,'EXP_DATE' AS [DataField/@fieldName]
      ,EXP_Date AS [DataField]
FROM SomeWhere
FOR XML PATH('Memory');
```

The empty string in the middle is needed to start a new element

And be aware, that the dateformat will be ISO8601 and not `190615` (you should be happy about this!)

Comment: It's Working Fine.Thank YOU..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve XML document creation from C#, then it can be achieved through ADO.net with Help of DataSet. Method name is DataSet.WriteXml(string Filename).